# Error : java.io.IOException: UT000036: Connection terminated parsing multipart data

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jhipster, undertow

I'm working with React Js and Jhipster(Spring boot) , I try to upload a file using MultipartFile.

Where I pass Request Method: POST.

With Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarykyl9Y0dZ1t72LO7Q

And server nginx

Here is the codes:

The controller

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/uploadCustomer", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public void uploadMultipart(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file,@RequestPart("tags") String tags ) {
        log.debug("tags "+tags+" {}",tags);
        myService.saveCustomerFromCSV(file,tags);
    }
```

part of configuration file

```
spring:
 servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: false
      file-size-threshold: 2KB
      max-file-size: 15MB
      max-request-size: 50MB
```

```
ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true
  ReadTimeout: 300000
  connection-timeout: 30000

# See http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html
zuul: # those values must be configured depending on the application specific needs
  sensitive-headers: Cookie,Set-Cookie #see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3126
  ignored-headers: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin
  host:
    max-total-connections: 1000
    max-per-route-connections: 100
    connect-timeout-millis: 60000
    socket-timeout-millis: 60000
  semaphore:
    max-semaphores: 500
```

But with Undertow, it throws RuntimeException , The Exception message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: UT000036: Connection terminated parsing multipart data
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:798)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getParameter(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:665)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:84)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:65)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:336)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: UT000036: Connection terminated parsing multipart data
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.MultiPartParserDefinition$MultiPartUploadHandler.parseBlocking(MultiPartParserDefinition.java:228)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:792)
        ... 42 common frames omitted
```

**Solution :**

In my case the Solution is to remove the Spring Servlet multipart Configuration which is in the gateway part

```
#spring:
#  servlet:
#    multipart:
#      enabled: false
#      file-size-threshold: 2KB
#      max-file-size: 15MB
#      max-request-size: 50MB
```